# Duplicate file finder based on comparing 1st 24 characters of file name

Tags: duplicates

I have more than 12000 files and I need to compare 1st 24 characters of each file name.
If match is found than need to delete it.

for e.g

> 1. dat_2016_08_13_11_01_02_1339.data
> 2. dat_2016_08_13_11_01_02_2140.data
> 3. dat_2016_08_13_12_47_33_1362.data
> 4. dat_2016_08_13_13_12_03_1062.data
> 5. dat_2016_08_13_13_12_03_0217.data

In above case :

File 1 is duplicate of 2 as 1st 24 characters "dat_2016_08_13_11_01_02" are same.

File 4 is duplicate of 5 as 1st 24 characters "dat_2016_08_13_13_12_03" are same.

FYI, date of file creation for file 1&2 is different. so, can't use attribute comparison.

I have gone through various duplicate file finder tools. no one gives the way to customize compare technique for my special need.

Can anyone suggest the way to do it ?

Comment: if on windows press ctrl +  F and search for "dat_2016_08_13_11_01_02" and then select all and delete

Comment: @Paul : this is just one example of set of duplicate files. there are more set of duplicate files. not possible to search 12000 file names manually.

Comment: Do you have java installed? because i just coded a java program to do this

Comment: @Paul : Yes I have java installed. I can try java program. -thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a program i quickly coded see if this helps:
Remember Change the directory

```
import java.io.File;

public class duplicates {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        File f=new File("C:/testfolder");//insert your directory here
        File[] files=f.listFiles();
        for(int y=0;y<files.length;y++){
            f=new File("C:/testfolder");
            files=f.listFiles();
            String find="";
            if(files[y].getName().length()>24){
            find=files[y].getName().substring(0,24);
            }else{
                continue;
            }
        for(int x=0;x<files.length;x++){

            if(files[x].getName().startsWith(find)){
                System.out.println("deleted file:"+files[x].getAbsolutePath());

                files[x].delete();
                break;
            }


        }
        }
            System.out.println("DONE!!");


}

}
```

I have not tested this with the large no. of files but it should work(might take a min or 2)

Hope this Helped:)